# Is using a TableEntity with only the desired property equivalent to a projection query?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have a series of `Report`s represented by a TableEntity. It has many different properties, but often, I only need the `ReportID` property.

```
public class ReportEntity : TableEntity
{
    public ReportIDEntity()
    {}

    internal ReportIDEntity(Guid reportID, .../*other properties*/)
    {
        ReportID = reportID;
        //assign other properties
    }

    public Guid ReportID { get; set; }

    //other properties
}
```

I've written a projection query for this, so that I won't have to retrieve the entire entity just to get the ID:

```
const String __ID_COLUMN = "ReportID"; //yuck
IEnumerable<Guid> ids =
_cloudTable_.ExecuteQuery(
new TableQuery<DynamicTableEntity>().Where(
    TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition(
        "PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, partitionKey))
    .Select(new[] { __ID_COLUMN }),
    (key, rowKey, timestamp, properties, etag) => properties[__ID_COLUMN].GuidValue.Value);
```

However, this is pretty ugly (I need to specify the property name as a string to retrieve it, and the code is long).

What if I make a TableEntity that only has the `ReportID` property, and query for that?
**Will this retrieve all of the data, or will it be as lean (bandwidth-wise) as the projection query?**

```
public class ReportIDEntity : TableEntity
{
    public ReportIDEntity()
    {}

    internal ReportIDEntity(Guid reportID)
    {
        ReportID = reportID;
    }

    public Guid ReportID { get; set; }
}

public class ReportEntity : ReportIDEntity
{
    public ReportEntity()
    {}

    internal ReportEntity(Guid reportID, .../*other properties*/)
     : base(reportID)
    {
        //assign other properties
    }
    //other properties
}
```

And then the query would be:

```
IEnumerable<Guid> reportEntities =
_cloudTable_.ExecuteQuery(
new TableQuery<ReportIDEntity>().Where(
    TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition(
        "PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, partitionKey)))
.Select(e => e.ReportID);
```

Comment: I believe that the query will return all attributes. An easy way to affirm this, is to use something like fiddler to intercept the query and what is returned.

Comment: @hocho I tested with fiddler and yes, it confirms the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, using `Query Projection` is more efficient because it is a server side operation and table service will only return the entities which will only contain `ReportID` attribute (property) thus less data flows over the network. When you use query without projection, all attributes are returned and except `ReportID` all other attributes are discarded on the client side during deserialization process.